# Laravel change project root directory path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My client developed a laravel project on his Appserv localhost server. I want to work on the project on my localhost server but I use Xampp instead of Appserv. I copied the project folder to the htdocs but it gives me the following error when I run the script.

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [index] not found.
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('index', array('C:\\AppServ\\www\\libraryapp\\project\\resources\\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
```

How can I change the following path

> 'C:\AppServ\www\libraryapp\' to 'C:\xampp\htdocs\libraryapp'

Answer (score 0):

The path that Laravel uses to look for views is defined in `config/views.php`. If you can't find the path `C:\AppServ\www\libraryapp\` there you can just add your own path `C:\xampp\htdocs\libraryapp` in that file and this will make the project work if the views are the only problem.

Comment: that is the problem. I cannot file that file where I need to make the change. I want to know which file it is

Comment: I don't see any option i the config/views file.

Comment: can you add the file contents to the question please @AjmalRazeel